# How to use generics with the value of a type definition in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have some classes which all have a property called *data*. I have a type definition for the data type mapping which I'd like to use in the generics definition. So this is my code:

```
type DataTypes = {
  age: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
};

abstract class AbstractBase<T extends DataTypes> {
  data: T;
}

class AgeComponent extends AbstractBase<DataTypes.age> {}

class FirstNameComponent extends AbstractBase<DataTypes.firstName> {}

class LastNameComponent extends AbstractBase<DataTypes.lastName> {}
```

So when using `abstract class AbstractBase<T extends DataTypes>` I'd like to tell TypeScript to accept the types according to the mappings in the type *DataTypes*.

Is this possible with TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass to `AbstractBase` the key from `DataTypes` you want to use, and the use index access types to get the type from `DataTypes`:

```
abstract class AbstractBase<T extends keyof DataTypes> {
  data!: DataTypes[T];
}

class AgeComponent extends AbstractBase<"age"> {}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAVcEDOUC8UDeAoKKOAcwgC4oA7AVwFsAjCAJwG4CoAzASybWADk4tclD5MulYm0IAbOH0HCKYiVLwBfNnjj0xcAMbAo+uWgwBBXcCYHgAIXkQAPEigQAHsAiUAJhgDWECAA9hywCMioaAB8uOw+EQCEFPCIKJBoANpIALps6nh4JvIWpADCwbRgwZTeRh5evhZWNoYOaM4ARCQQnbE4BUWmGABiPApCEBVVNXVunt5+UJZ6bY5Ondy8ApN9uIPFZlAAMvI7wtPVtZT1C03LLbbtXabnvf3qQA)

Or you can pass the type of the property directly:

```
abstract class AbstractBase<T extends DataTypes[keyof DataTypes]> {
  data!: T;
}

class AgeComponent extends AbstractBase<DataTypes["age"]> {}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAVcEDOUC8UDeAoKKOAcwgC4oA7AVwFsAjCAJwG4CoAzASybWADk4tclD5MulYm0IAbOH0HCKYiVLwBfNnjj0xcAMbAo+uWgwBBXcCYHgAIXkQAPEigQAHsAiUAJhniIKJBoANoA1hAgAPYcsAjIqGgAugB8uOw+8QCEFEhs6nh4JvIWpADCUbRgUZTeRh5evhZWNoYOaM4BCcEhAEQkEL2puAVFphgAYjwKQhAVVTV1bp7eflCWem2OTl1B6H3cvAKzQ2k4o8VmUAAy8sfC89W1lPUrTesttu2d8XuhvaZ7oNhucgA)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Index access type` as `.` ones do not work in Typescript

```
type DataTypes = {
  age: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
};

abstract class AbstractBase<T extends DataTypes[keyof DataTypes]> {
  data !: T;
}

class AgeComponent extends AbstractBase<DataTypes["age"]> {
}

class FirstNameComponent extends AbstractBase<DataTypes["firstName"]> {}

class LastNameComponent extends AbstractBase<DataTypes["lastName"]> {}


// Test the inference 

new AgeComponent().data // number

new FirstNameComponent().data // string

new LastNameComponent().data // string
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAVcEDOUC8UDeAoKKOAcwgC4oA7AVwFsAjCAJwG4CoAzASybWADk4tclD5MulYm0IAbOH0HCKYiVLwBfNnjj0xcAMbAo%20uWgwBBXcCYHgAIXkQAPEigQAHsAiUAJhniIKJBoANoA1hAgAPYcsAjIqGgAugB8uOw%208VAAhBRIbOp4eCbyFqQAwlG0YFGU3kYeXr4WVjaGDmjOAQnBIQBEJBB9qemFxaYYAGI8CkIQldW19W6e3n5Qlnrtjk7dQej93LwCc8NpOGMlZlAAMvInwgs1dZQNq80brbYdXfH7oX1TA8hiMLkU8AB6CFQJDoIzAAAW0AkHGY3n00CKdQA7hsKlVnvUABQASgAdJlEFAoVQ6IwmFiILjpsdFPMCUtXqSKVkaSpJIzcXdZo8OS9gNzKXBqdD%20cQ8EA)